# Android App crashes in simple if statement

Tags: java, android

It seems very weird a check that i have to make to see if the object is null or empty.

My code:

```
if(objectList == null || objectList.isEmpty()) {
   //Log error here
}
```

After writing this if statement if the objectList is null it crashes saying that it cannot check if empty in a null object reference. Why is this happening?

Comment: if its null so how you can check that is empty or not

Comment: this problem does not look like a possible one. Maibe you use Instant Run, and your code is not up to date in the device?

Comment: @PhanVanLinh, this will cause NPE in case if objectList  is null.

Comment: it causes NPE...i already done this with 2 if statements but the point is why i cannot merge it to one with a double condition

Comment: have you read my first comment?

Comment: Can you please post little more code?

Comment: Please post little more code and crash log for better solution. You if looks good though. If objectList is null then it's goes inside if but if it's not null then it check for second condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can call `objectList.isEmpty()`, make sure that your `objectList` is not `null`. Thus you should do this:

```
if(objectList != null && !objectList.isEmpty()) {
   // not empty
}
else {
   // objectList is null or empty
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Find the solution

```
if((objectList !=null) && (objectList.size()>0)) {
   // your implemention 
}else{
   // your error log here
}
```

Comment: isn't it just a flipped `if` from the question?

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
if(objectList != null) {
if(objectList.isEmpty())
{
//Log here is empty
}
}
else
{
// log here its null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try and catch

```
    try{
      if(objectList == null || objectList.isEmpty()) {
}catch(Exception e){
//print the exception
}
```

app will not crash

Comment: As the question was mostly focused on keeping the app running. so it will do the thing.